# How to enable "Access to Cloud Managed Developer ID Certificate" in App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

As an Admin in App Store Connect, the setting `Access to Cloud Managed Developer ID Certificate` is disabled / greyed out. I cannot check this box for users on other accounts. Any idea how I can enable and tick this box?

1. Log in to App Store Connect
2. Select the "Users and Access" tab
3. Select a user
4. Under "Additional Resources", I cannot check "Access to Cloud Managed Developer ID Certificate"

[image: Screenshot of settings in App Store Connect]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I contacted Apple Developer Support over this issue and they responded that this `Access to Cloud Managed Developer ID Certificate` setting is **only modifiable by the Account Holder** role.

Furthermore, access to this setting can only be given to Admins. **Access cannot be given to any other roles** in App Store Connect.

For example, our Account Holder successfully gave access to one of our Admins. When the Account Holder tried to give access to this setting to any Developer, he wasn't able to click the checkmark. Apple said this is expected behaviour. On Wednesday, June 8, 2022, I asked Apple for a feature request to allow an Account Holder to give a Developer role access. That's all I can do.

If you are experiencing this issue, please go to the [Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/) page and click the "Contact Us" button in the top right corner. **Please politely ask Apple to change this access**, so Apple knows it's a priority, and will make the change.